# How can I pull git submodule automatically?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am assigned a project, where I will be doing backend development and another person will be handling frontend development. There is a requirement that the frontend developer does not have access to the development server, nor the project code. So, we decided to create another repository just for frontend.

The problem is that I don't know how to make submodule to immediately pull from the remote server when something is committed to the remote repo. I need the developer to commit and immediately see the change in the frontend.

I have been reading about git hooks and I have found that I can do this using `post-receive` hook. However, it doesn't seem to work. Here is what I did:

1. From the main project's root directory, I found the following directory /.git/modules/submodule-directory/hooks
2. I created `post-receive` file with executable permission allowed.
3. Contents of `post-receive` file:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   git pull
   ```
4. Pushed a change from my local machine to the submodule repo but nothing happened.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I am going to clarify some points regarding my question.

I have two repositories: The "main" repository, which is the entire project; and another repository, which is frontend stuff (views, assets etc). Let's call this "frontend" repository.

To my main repository, I added frontend repo as a submodule, located inside /submodules/frontend. This way, the outsourced frontend developers will not be able to see anything about the actual project. They will only see what they are working on.

This actually works perfectly in terms of access control and I can easily monitor the frontend development's progress separately from project. But there is one problem that I don't know how to do.

Our project has two separate servers - a development server and a production server. The development server needs to always be in the master branch for both main repo and frontend repo. This way, both frontend team and the backend team will be able to see their updates. Even though frontend team mainly works with templates, the templates have access to data that is stored in the database and are using a lot of stuff that are integrated to backend (e.g models).

In order for this "system" to work, I need the frontend repo to always fetch and merge whenever there is a new commit in "frontend" **remote** repo. In other words, if the frontend team does `git commit` and `git push`, the "frontend" repo submodule in the development server needs to immediately `git pull`. So, when the frontend guys go test their stuff, they will immediately see the latest changes.

I read that `post-receive` hook can do that but I need this hook to exist only for submodule. So, after some digging I found that all the submodule hooks exist in `/.git/modules/submodules/frontend/hooks`. So, I created `post-receive` hook in that directory with the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh
git pull
```

But this didn't work. My question is how to make the hooks work with post-receive inside submodule?

I know the route that I have taken is far from perfect but this is the only way that makes sense to me when it comes to allowing devs to only access one directory without having access to the development server.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: A manual `git pull` might give you a hint

Comment: Another precision misses: for example about the development server, you push from your local to a repository located where ? to a `--bare` repository? directly to the directory used in development ?

Comment: I am pushing to a `--bare` repository located in Gitlab.com

Comment: ok so you have 2 local repository (on your local machine), 2 remotes where you push (gitlab) and 2 others on the development server (let's not talk about the production one yet).

Comment: Yes I do. And I want each repository from dev server to pull from their corresponding remote repositories whenever local repositories push to their remote repos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `git pull`, this is (basically) equivalent to `git fetch && git merge`. This will not update submodules.

If I understand your needs, What you want can be done with the commands `git submodule update` (or  `git submodule foreach 'git pull'`) in your post-receive hooks (in the main .git/hooks directory).

ADD (based on your editions): based on what I understood, you need to add the `post-receive` hook on the gitlab frontend repository, and your hook must execute the command `git submodule update` (or maybe `git submodule foreach 'git fetch && git merge'`  in the development server (with a ssh command or something).

But it may be easier to rethink how your development server is installed, you can install the 2 repos as totally separated (not frontend being a submodule), and maybe adding the submodule/frontend to your .gitignore directory. This not necessarily means you have to remove `frontend` from the submodule, but just not using it in your development server.

Comment: I wasn't very clear in my question. I want to add a hook to a submodule that will work on its own. So, if I am committing something to the main repository, it doesn't update the submodule. Submodule is only updated when there is a change in submodule's remote repository.

Comment: Still seems unclear to me about what you call `commit to main repository` `commit` ≠ `push` ? local submodule repo ? remote submodule repo ? local "main project repo", etc.

Comment: I always commit and push, so I just say commit. Please see my edit. I have clarified all the terminology that I am using and the way I want it to work. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: it's a bad habit to use the same names for 2 totally different things ;) I made some precisions on my answer