# How to add a git hook to update submodule with git pull & commit it into my PR

Tags: git, github, githooks

I want to `commit` a `hook` to my PR which automatically `update the submodule` whenever someone does a `git pull`

Following is what is did in my git local repo:

```
touch .git/hooks/post-rewrite
cd .git/hooks
chmod +x post-rewrite
```

Next, to the `post-rewrite` I added the code from [here](https://gist.github.com/digitaljhelms/f74eaf56835262d6bf3f)

Now if I do a `git pull` shouldn't it update the `submodule with`git pull` as I am expecting it to? But it doesn't. **What is the mistake I am doing?**

I've looked through many related links which are there but can't get it to work.

Also if I want to `commit` it the add `post-rewrite` file in hooks folder does not enlist under `git status`. **How can I get `add`, `commit` & `push` this into my PR?**

Comment: What led you to believe post-rewrite is the correct hook for this? Also, what led you to believe git might inject hooks via pull? Please be concrete.

Comment: @jthill I read through some links like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37525188/how-can-i-pull-git-submodule-automatically) & [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427207/can-git-hook-scripts-be-managed-along-with-the-repository) & some more which say that to achieve a automatic `submodule update` with `git pull`, you need to add a `post-rewrite` or `post-receive` in `.git/hooks/`. Hence I did the same. Did not work. Moreover it does not list in `git status` as well. I am confused. Please suggest. All I want is whenever a developer does a git pull, submodule update automatically

Comment: Do I need to change or enable some gitAttribute to enable hooks ?

Comment: "rewrite" does not appear anywhere in either of those links, nor can I find any suggestion that git might inject hooks via pull. So let me repeat: what led you to believe post-rewrite is the correct hook for this? Also, what led you to believe git might inject hooks via pull? Please be concrete.  You enable hooks in exactly the way you've shown in your question.

Comment: @jthill  My objective is "To Ensure `git submodule update` automatically happens for every developer in my team who does a `git pull`"... Now I need to figure out how to do this. I see that `git hooks` is the potential solution to my problem. Now I am trying all kinds of hit & trial things & seeking help in this forum. Please post a solution as answer if you can. I read the official git documentation & now understand that I need to create a hooks directory in my git folder & create a symlink to it? As mentioned at https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-hooks ?

Comment: Ok. Now I learnt that I need to create directory called `hooks` in my main repo, create a `post-update` script & somehow simlink it to `.git/hooks/post-update` ? I am still not sure. Would appreciate any solutions posted for this